# how to send an numpy array or a pytorch Tensor through http post request using requests module and Flask

Tags: python, numpy, flask, python-requests, pytorch

I have an image and I want to send it to the serve. I'm using `requests` module to perform simple post request as following(info is a dictionary):

```
    import requests

    print(type(info["array_image"]))
    print(type(info["visual_features"]))
    response = requests.post("url", data=info)
```

output :

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'torch.Tensor'>
```

on the server side I'm trying to receive them as arrays at least:

```
from flask import Flask, request

@app.route('/path', methods=['POST'])
def function_name():
    visual_features = request.form['visual_features']
    array_image = request.form['array_image']
    print(type(array_image))
    print(type(visual_features))
```

output:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

I want to get a bytes array to build the image, but what I'm getting is a string...
If I didn't find a way I'll encode arrays in bas64 and then decode it in the server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @praba230890 for giving me an easy to follow example.

I would still write the solution here down, since the provided link doesn't fit my case exactly.

```
import pickle
import io

bytes_image = pickle.dumps(info["array_image"])
stream = io.BytesIO(bytes_image)
files = {"bytes_image": stream}

info["array_image"] = None

response = http.post("url", data=info, files=files)
```

and in the server side:

```
from flask import Flask, request

@app.route('/path', methods=['POST'])
def function_name():
    image = request.files.get('bytes_image')
    bytes_image = image.read()
```

if you want to get the image from a file, then:

```
requests.post("http://localhost:5000/predict",
                 files={"file": open('<PATH/TO/.jpg/FILE>/cat.jpg','rb')})
```

## **The Solution I'm currently using:**

remember `info["array_image"]` is a numpy array, and `info` is a dictionary

```
    import io
    info["image_shape_width"] = info["array_image"].shape[0]
    info["image_shape_height"] = info["array_image"].shape[1]

    bytes_image = info["array_image"].tobytes()
    stream = io.BytesIO(bytes_image)
    files = {"bytes_image": stream}

    info["array_image"] = None

    response = http.post(self.ip + "path", data=info, files=files)
```

then receive it

```
    from flask import Flask, request
    import numpy as np

    @app.route('/path', methods=['POST'])
    def function_name():    
        bytes_image = request.files.get('bytes_image')
        bytes_image = bytes_image.read()
        array_image = np.frombuffer(bytes_image, dtype=dtype)
        shape = (int(request.form['image_shape_width']), int(request.form['image_shape_height']), 3)         
        array_image = np.reshape(array_image, shape)
                                       
        image = Image.fromarray(array_image)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert your data to proper JSON or use Python [pickle module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) or if you have an image as you've mentioned you can send it as a file (multipart request) to the server as shown in the examples [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/flask_rest_api_tutorial.html#integrating-the-model-in-our-api-server).

Comment: this is the half way...it worked, but I'm saving the image in a file then I pass the file to the post request...this is not good because I have to save every image in the storage, I want to pass a file without storing it